# NSTimer stops iphone sound?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, jailbreak

I have to call a function call myfunc after a specific interval of time in my app and this func runs forever.However ,the problem is whenever I use the following code my iphone sound goes away.

```
self.now = [NSDate date] ;
    self.timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:self.now
                                          interval:100
                                            target:self
                                          selector:@selector(myfunc)
                                          userInfo:nil
                                           repeats:YES] ;
    self.runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runLoop addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [self.runLoop runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10000]];
```

Only the ringtone sound works.All other sound stops working.Like the keypad lock sound and the volume bars which let you adjust your iphone volume also go away.Please tell me what I am doing wrong which damages the iphone sound.

I am pretty sure this is the piece of code that stops iphone sound.When I comment it the sound starts working. Does anybody know a solution to this method? If not ,does anybody know of another method to perform the same functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSTimer` are paused when the app is in background state.

You'll have to start some background task to do what you want. But even with that, you will be limited to a certain amount of time after the app was put in background.

Real backgrounding behavior is only granted for location tracking, VoIP or Audio apps. Other apps must face limitations: once in background, you are given an amount of time to complete tasks you start with `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` (backgroundTimeRemaining).

The whole thing is described in iOS Application Programming Guide, Executing Code in the Background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 100.0 
                                                    target: self 
                                                  selector: @selector(myFunc) 
                                                  userInfo: nil 
                                                   repeats: YES];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer: myTimer forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

// selector implementation

```
- (void) myFunc {      
    NSLog(@"myFunc");
}
```